# XPath/XSLT 1.0: Identifying element based on a sub element value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am developing a XSLT translation which can only use xslt 1.0 with XPath 1.0.
Let's assume I have the following xml and I want to select the object which original_file_name attribute ends with ".prt". How can I do this?

```
<object>
    <object>
        <attribute name="original_file_name">file1.qaf</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute1">val</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute2">val</attribute>
    </object>
    <object>
        <attribute name="original_file_name">file2.tso</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute1">Second guess</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute2">val</attribute>
    </object>
    <object>
        <attribute name="original_file_name">file3.prt</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute1">First guess!</attribute>
        <attribute name="otherAttribute2">val</attribute>
    </object>
</object>
```

For XSLT 2.0, I have found a solution, but I can't get rid of the index-of which is not supported in XPath 1.0. Do you have any hints for a solution?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/object">
        <xsl:variable name="fileIndex">
            <xsl:call-template name="identifyFile">
                <xsl:with-param name="fileNames" select="object/attribute[@name='original_file_name']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="fileObj" select="object[position()=$fileIndex]"/>

        <!-- do sth. with fileObj -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$fileObj" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="identifyFile">
        <xsl:param name="fileNames"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- add other file extensions here -->
            <xsl:when test="$fileNames['.prt'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of($fileNames, $fileNames['.prt'=substring(., string-length() - 3)])" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$fileNames['.tso'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of($fileNames, $fileNames['.tso'=substring(., string-length() - 3)])" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- if no known file extension has been found, just take the default one. -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Simplified the problem too much in the first step :). I have added a 2nd file extension which should be searched for in case the first one is not found. So if in the example is no '.prt'-file, the '.tso'-file should be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to select based on a condition then the XPath expression

```
object[attribute[@name='original_file_name' and substring(., string-length() - 3) = '.prt']]
```

in your `copy-of` should suffice. With your edited sample I think you simply want

```
   <xsl:template match="/object">
     <xsl:variable name="fileNames" select="object/attribute[@name='original_file_name']"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- add other file extensions here -->
            <xsl:when test="$fileNames['.prt'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$fileNames['.prt'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$fileNames['.tso'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$fileNames['.tso'=substring(., string-length() - 3)]" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- if no known file extension has been found, just take the default one. -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$fileNames[1]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This would be so simple. I've probably simplified my initial problem too much. But I keep thinking if there is also such a one-liner for my real problem. Any more ideas?

Comment: It seems you know how to select the element you want, instead of simply to do that you first compute an index and then return that to select based on the index. In that case you should simply select and return in one step. I will edit.

Comment: I came up with a solution like this one yesterday! :) Thank you for your help!